# How do I detect signature from emai using IMAP client for Java?

Tags: email, signature

How do I detect signatures from email while parsing email from IMAP client. I don't want to show the details of user (such as name, contact number, LinkedIn profile link etc, which are sometimes part of signatures in email)
Signatures may be in various formats such as

> Best, Name contact: xxxx

or

> LinkedIn profile or image

or

> sent from iphone etc.

I am currently not willing to user any library, as they might save data which is not in my choice. 
I've gone through other support answers & other open source libraries, but their are some problems. Is their any other way someone has figured out,
Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: A really, really hard question. Easier for HTML mail, you can look for some CSS classes (class=gmail_signature for example). For text/plain and some HTML, if a line is dash dash space the rest is usually a signature. You can also look at other mail same sender and see whether they end in the same way.

Comment: Initially I thought of this. Have to check whether I can parse the class name or something like this.

Comment: I've used jsoup for that.